# How can i sync images from local windows forms application to web forms application

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, stored-procedures

I have a windows forms application..How can i am syncing the databases from local database to online database but how can i sync the images

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the correct scenario so that anybody can help

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819079%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Here is some syncing code using wcf ..Hope this helps..